# Avoiding unintended rudeness or accusatory tones in reminder emails

Tags: business-writing, email, letter, vocabulary

I am in one of the newsletter teams of my company. Last week, I had mailed the Vice-President of our company to write an article for our newsletter, to which he replied in affirmative and mailed me back that he would send that article by the end of this week.

I decided to write a reminder mail to him today asking him whether he can send that article by the end of this week and if not then he should let me know. But I'm kinda stuck in making this email sound gentle.

Here's what I've written so far:

> Hello XXX,
>
> Good Morning!
>
> Recognizing your very busy schedule, I’m sending you this mail as a reminder to your article for the newsletter.

Then, that's it. I'm stuck at this point so as to use what words inorder not to make this mail sound rude.

Can you guys help me on this front. He is the Vice-President of my company and I really don't want to sound rude.

Comment: @John Smithers How do you make the "text of the mail" appear differently than the rest of the question, as you've done above for this question?

Comment: bengaluria, hit the "edit" button and you see it. Just put a ">" at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good morning XXX,

I wanted to touch base with you about the status of your article for the newsletter. Please advise whether you will be able to send it to me by the end of the week. If it doesn't work with your schedule, that's fine; I just need to know one way or the other for planning purposes.

Thanks!

Regards,
[your name]

Comment: Thanks... that looks good. Regarding the subject name, I've thought about two names: "Gentle Remainder for the article" or "status of the newsletter article". Which one do you suggest? Is it appropriate to use the word "remainder" in the subject of an email?

Comment: (1) It isn't "remainder" (something which is left over, or remains), it's "reminder" (bringing something to your attention out of your memory, re-minding) (2) I'd use "Newsletter article" and leave the status question for the body of the email. Don't tell him you're being gentle. That comes off as condescending or rude.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was by mistake that I wrote "remainder" instead of "reminder". Coming back to the mail, even I felt "gentle" in the subject could sound rude. So, thanks once again for your valuable inputs.